# How to split a DL at the DT level

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup - I have a requirement to split the DL at every occurance of a DT into a new column, with the DD items that are 'owned' by the DT falling beneath it

```
<dl class="yearly-events-split">
    <dt>2015</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 Title - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dt>2016</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 5 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 6 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dt>2017</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dt>2018</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
</dl>

<hr />

<style>
    dl.yearly-events-split {
        border: 3px double #ccc;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

    dl.yearly-events-split dt {
        width: 25%;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: green;
        float: left;
    }

    dl.yearly-events-split dd {
        width: 25%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    }

</style>
```

I'm wanting to achieve this using a DL since then it will turn into a nice list when I apply a media query to make them full-width on a tablet or mobile device

The intended layout would be

```
2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018
Event | Event | Event | Event 
Event | Event | Event | Event 
Event | Event | Event | 
Event
```

There are a variable number of DDs that fall beneath each DT - so the column heights will naturally vary

I'm guessing I should be able to do this with CSS3 Columns - but I cannot for the life of me work out how

Comment: `dl` is not the right choice for this kind of list. `dl`s are used for list of pairs of terms and descriptions i.e. key-value pairs. Your's is a use-case for `ul/li`.

Comment: Yes I understood that used to be the case - but I was reading on MaxDesign that the usage of DLs has changed in recent years - http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/ Others believe that definition lists can be used to tie together any items that have a direct relationship with each other

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html

Comment: ok - but since my content is already in DL - a CSS solution would be far easier than going back and having the output rewritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way using table displays, removing all floats and widths:

```
dl {
  display: table;   
}

dt {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 -32px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

dt + dd {margin-top: 30px}
```

[jsFiddle example here:](http://jsfiddle.net/u59fzes5/)

PD: The negative `margin-left: -32px` means that 32px is the width of the dt element, so if you plan to give any width to your dt elements, the negative margin left should be the same as the width of the dt element.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too convinced about the use of `dl` (description lists) here. `dl`s are used for list of pairs of terms and descriptions i.e. key-value pairs. Your's is a use-case for `ul/li`. Your use-case isn't implying that the events are a description or meaning of the year. It is more of a hierarchical list of events grouped by year.

Ref [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).

You can easily use `ul/li` and you don't even need media queries. They will be responsive on their own. Further, you could use CSS `columns` to format those in the way you want. Try resizing in the example fiddle below, and see that they will neatly tile up.

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
ul {
    list-style: none; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;
    -webkit-column-width: 120px;
    column-width: 120px;
}
ol, ul > li {
    list-style: none; 
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
ul > li { background-color: #cce; font-weight: bold; }
ol { background-color: #eee; font-weight: normal; }
li { padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<ul class="yearly-events-split">
    <li>2015
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 Title - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
    <li>2016
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 5 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 6 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
    <li>2017
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
    <li>2018
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
</ul>

<hr />
```

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lhbsp320/1/**

---

### Edit:

If you really insist on keeping your `dl / dt`s because of not being able to change the markup, then you could use the same CSS for those as well.

Of course, you would then need to add media queries to adjust the display.

**Demo Snippet 2:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
dl {
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;
    -webkit-column-width: 120px;
    column-width: 120px;
}
dt {
    -webkit-column-break-before: always;
    column-break-before: always;
}
dd {
    list-style: none; 
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
dt { background-color: #cce; font-weight: bold; }
dd { background-color: #eee; font-weight: normal; }
dt, dd { padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<dl class="yearly-events-split">
    <dt>2015</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 Title - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dt>2016</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 5 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 6 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dt>2017</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dt>2018</dt>
    <dd>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
    <dd>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></dd>
</dl>
```

**Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ghqor2q8/**

---

### Edit 2:

If you need to reliably support Firefox, then you could use `display: table` to layout your `ul/li`. You would need media queries for smaller lower viewports.

**Demo Snippet 3:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
ul {
    list-style: none; display: table;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;
}
ul > li { list-style: none; display: table-cell; }
ul > li { background-color: #cce; font-weight: bold; }
ol { list-style: none; background-color: #eee; font-weight: normal; }
li { padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<ul class="yearly-events-split">
    <li>2015
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 Title - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
    <li>2016
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 5 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 6 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
    <li>2017
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
    <li>2018
  <ol>
   <li>Event 1 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 2 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 3 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
   <li>Event 4 - <span class="event-date">18th January - 20th January 2016</span></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
</ul>

<hr />
```

**Demo Fiddle 3: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/vxnyn225/1/**

Comment: Sorry - unless I missed it - does this split into the four columns?

Comment: @DavidMiles: (1) I have added the `dl/dt` css as well. (2) It will split into as many columns that can be accommodated into a size of 120px. You can tweak this size as per your need. If all columns cannot be accomodated because of smaller viewport, then they will start tiling neatly. However, in case of `dl/dt` they will not (*they will overflow*) and you will have to use media queries.

Comment: Sorry looking at it in Firefox

It is year followed by the events - then year followed by the events - I am not seeing columns at all

Comment: @DavidMiles: O yes. Columns are tricky with Gecko. Also, you will need some `-moz` prefixes. Give me some time. Shall try to work it out.

Comment: I've made progress with this


    dl.yearly-events-split {
        border: 3px double #ccc;
        padding: 0.5em;
        -moz-columns: 4;
        -webkit-columns: 4;
        columns: 4;

    }

    dl.yearly-events-split dt {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: green;
        -moz-page-break-after: avoid;
        -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
        break-after: avoid;
    }

    dl.yearly-events-split dd {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
        -moz-page-break-before: avoid;
        -webkit-column-break-before: avoid;
        break-before: avoid;
    }

Comment: But it doesnt respect me wanting the DDs to only be under their own parent

Comment: Firefox has serious limitations. See this bug report - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549114. `break-before` is also not implemented. See this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @DavidMiles: I have added another edit to the answer. It seems your best bet would be to use `ul/li` along with `display:table` for first-level `li` and `display:table-cell` for the second-level. Supporting Firefox with columns is a pain.